# apply layer style to part of an image

Tags: adobe-photoshop, mask

I have a (png) logo with lettering and artwork above (and not touching) the lettering. How can I mask or isolate the lettering portion, in order to apply a layer style to only the artwork portion of the image in Photoshop.

Comment: I'm confused, you seem to know exactly how to do this - use layer masks. So what's the question..?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the 'Layer Style / Blending Options' (double click on the fx within Layers) - there's a checkbox called 'Layer Mask Hides effects'.

Answer (score 1):

As Ryan's comment says:

Duplicate your layer.

Then isolate part of the lettering on one of the layers, either by  [adding a layer mask](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/masking-layers.html) OR by deleting the other portion of the logo.

Apply your layer style to the layer you need it to be applied on.

You should end up with 2 layers; one with the effect, one without. You can merge them after if you want but some effects might change appearance when flattened.

---

To my knowledge, there is no way to add a style to only a part of a layer.